# NSThread doesn't execute selector

Tags: ios, nsthread

I have a static object that fires a thread, but whenever the thread tries to execute the selector i get a "[NSThread initWithTarget:selector:object:]: target does not implement selector" and the app crashes

heres my code:

```
@implementation currentUser
{
    NSThread *engineThread;
}

-(void)MessageEngineStart{
    NSLog(@"[MDS]:Message Engine Started!");    
    if(engineThread == nil){
        engineThread = [[NSThread alloc]init];
    }

    if(!engineThread.isExecuting){
        [engineThread performSelectorInBackground:@selector(job) withObject:nil];//here is where it crashes
        NSLog(@"[MDS]: Thread Will perform job in background.");
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"[MDS]: Thread is being executed.");
    }
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:30 target:self selector:@selector(MessageEngineStart) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}
-(void)job
{
   //JOB
}
```

both thread and job are on the same object.
if I just use a

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(job) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
```

everything goes well...

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to create a thread for this, you should just be calling

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(job) withObject:nil];
```

because it is your class which implements `job` and not the `NSThread` class. When you call

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(job) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
```

your are using `NSThread` to call `job` on `self` so it works.

Comment: indeed I though about that, but I need to perform this job every 30 seconds. My timer calls the the method "messageEngineStart" every 30 seconds. if I call the [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(job) withObject:nil]; all the time... would that create a new thread every time? making the stack bigger and bigger?

Comment: That's fine, though you should consider using a repeating timer. The timer is the trigger and then you can start your background thread in one of a number of ways. How the threads are created or reused by `performSelectorInBackground` you don't really need to worry about. You should write thread safe code in this case anyway.